# Skewness in SPSS - SPSS answers differently in multiple PC

Tags: statistics, spss

I'm wanna calculate the Skewness of 10 data(number); But SPSS calculate it differently in multiple computer!!!

The Numbers:
239.00, 
176.00, 
235.00, 
217.00, 
234.00, 
216.00, 
318.00, 
190.00, 
181.00, 
225.00.

I followed this steps:
Analysis--->Descriptive Statistics--->Frequencies--->Statistics--->Skewness--->Continue--->Ok

1. Answer of SPSS in one pc:

[image]

2. Answer of SPSS in another pc:

[image]

I really don't know why? And what should I've done?
Please help me... I need it a lot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have the values set to format differently on the second computer, so you are seeing the rounded value.  Double click the table, and click in the skewness cell to see the full precision value (or use Format > Cell Properties) to get more decimals.  Also, you can compare the mean and variance to make sure that the data is really the same on both.

Comment: No!
Both of them are the same with 3 decimal precision!

Comment: But isn't it the case that when you double click the item and look at the full value you see the same  number?